# ARCH modelling, DataScaleWarning: y is poorly scaled

Tags: python, dataframe, variance, volatility, arch

I'm currently facing an issue with GARCH modelling in python. Came across a datascale issue, where y is poorly scaled. Would really appreciate if could get an explanation on the error and perhaps a fix to the issue. GARCH model still runs but with warning messages of no successful convergence.

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcORn.png)

This is the data which I used for my y-values. It is taken from the residual values of an ARIMA model which i did.

[Y-dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s98u9.png)

GARCH output:

[fit output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EpgX.png)

[GARCH output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttdEH.png)

*Update
After setting `rescale=False`
[inequality constraints incompatible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQQrJ.png)

Minimal reproducable example

```
import pandas_datareader.data as pdr
import numpy as np
import datetime
import arch
from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA


#Extract Data, create column log returns
eurusd = pdr.DataReader('DEXUSEU', 'fred', start='1/1/2010', end='31/12/2019')
eurusd.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(eurusd.index).to_period('D')
eurusd = eurusd.to_timestamp()

eurusd['LR'] = np.log(eurusd) - np.log(eurusd.shift(1))

# ARIMA model
arima_model = ARIMA(eurusd.LR.dropna(), order=(1,0,1)).fit()
print(arima_model.summary())

# GARCH model
am = arch.arch_model(arima_model.resid)
res = am.fit()
print(res.summary())
```

### Heading

Comment: The warning message contains suggestions; have you tried any of them?

Comment: It will be easier for someone to help you if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Could you explain more on 'rescale' or what i means by y being poorly scaled.

Comment: Apparently the [variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance) of the data that you passed to the ARCH model is 8.307e-6.  A suggestion in the warning is to multiply your data by 1000 before processing it with ARCH.

Comment: Will try the following, it seems that it has solved the issue with convergence. Just curious would there be any problems with forecasting, estimation or accuracy with those errors?